# Color of 'ls' changed after zsh upgrade

Tags: bash, zsh, ls

I am currently using `zsh 5.0.2 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)`, when doing `ls` the folders was showing in blue, but after an upgrade everything is in white .. When doing `ls --color=auto` or `ls --color=tty` it goes back to normal. How to make it permanent? What configurations should I change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### How to make it permanent? What configurations should I change?

Add the following [alias](http://ss64.com/bash/alias.html) to the end of `~/.zshrc`:

```bash
alias ls='ls --color=auto'
```

Comment: Note: The long option "--color" misses one hyphen.

Comment: @A.Loiseau Thanks. Bad cut and paste :/